# Sponsoring a new account's inital account requirement?

Tags: transactions, go-sdk

The blog post here indicates that the minimum initial account balance can be sponsored:
https://www.stellar.org/blog/protocol-14-improvements?locale=en

However, my attempts of modifying the GO sponsored reserves example to do this were not successful:
https://developers.stellar.org/docs/glossary/sponsored-reserves/

How do you create such a transaction with txnbuild?